# Sending and rendering HTML syntax via jinja variable

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I need some complicated operations to render some **dynamic trees** in my `front-end`. But as I can't find any way to run recursion in my `jinja` or `front-end`, I take an approach to make a **string** in my `views.py` along with `HTML syntax` and render them in the `front-end` to get the desired output something like this (*As an example, here I skip the original complicated string because there is no need for it*):

in `views.py`:

```
test = "<h2>Hi This is from django</h2><ol><li>abc</li><li>mno</li><li>xyz</li></ol>"

mydict={
    'test' : test,
}
return render(request, 'app\index.html', mydict)
```

In `index.html`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    {{ test }}
</div>
```

My **desired output** with this code is:

> ### Hi This is from
> django
>
> 1. abc
> 2. mno
> 3. xyz

But the **obtain output** is:

```
<h2>Hi This is from django</h2><ol><li>abc</li><li>mno</li><li>xyz</li></ol>
```

Please suggest to me, is there any way to render the `jinja` **string** variable *along with the effect of `HTML`* in my `front-end`? If not then how can I take an approach to render any **tree** dynamically in my `front-end` where the level, leaf node, intermediate node, etc all info come from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the django-template-filter **safe** for this.

```
 {{ test | safe }}
```